# Why does the onError method keep getting invoked(Firebase)?

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, android-studio-2.1

I'm working with fire base and I'm following the creating a user account code on their website
->https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/login/password.html.

```
 public class RegisterFragment extends Fragment {
private final String FIREBASE_URL = "(MyFirebaseURL)";
private Firebase fRef;
private EditText etUserName;
private EditText etEmail;
private EditText etPassword;
private EditText etConfirmPassword;
private Button bSubmit;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register,container,false);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(getActivity());

    fRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);

    fRef.createUser("(hardcodedEmail)", "(hardcodedPassword)", new Firebase.ValueResultHandler<Map<String, Object>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Map<String, Object> result) {

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Registration Successful! UID: " + result.get("uid"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"There was an error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
    });
```

...And for some reason the onError() method gets invoked.
Why is that?

In case this helps, I first use "Firebase.setAndroidContext(getActivity());" in my LoginFragment.

Comment: why don't you examine the `FirebaseError firebaseError` variable, somehow I think it will answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the create user method with a hardcoded email and password, so it is extremely probable that firebase is returning an error because it cannot create the same user twice, if you are not deleting it from the web console after each try. Anyways the FirebaseError usually have all the information you need  about why it doesn't work. so you should check it out

Comment: I actually ensure my DB is clear before creating new users.